# create DLL instead of .lib from python file by cythonizing it

Tags: python, dll, cythonize

I want to generate .dll files from Python files. I tried cythonizing python files . But it gives .lib file instead of .dll file . How to get dll files from python .

Cythonizing code

```
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
    Extension("mymodule1",  ["mymodule1.py"]),
]
setup(
    name = 'My Program Name',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not "giving" you both?

Comment: yes,its only giving .lib